# Positioning the vanishing point with CSS transforms

Tags: css, transform

I'm trying to use CSS transforms to create a flat 'floor' which disappears off to infinity. The horizon where the vanishing point is needs to be half-way up the browser window.

I'm finding that I can't set up the perspective transform in a way that doesn't involve hard coding a size; the `perspective:` CSS property requires an absolute size. I've found `perspective-origin:`, which claims to let me set the position of the vanishing point, but it doesn't appear to do what I expect.

Here is some sample code:

```
<div id="container"><div id="floor"/></div>

#container
{
    perspective: 100px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#floor
{
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: -50000%; /* extend the element to 'infinity' */
    bottom: 0;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    transform: rotateX(30deg);
}
```

(JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/u29qk8a8/)

If you resize the preview pane in the fiddle, you'll see that while the vanishing point does move, it doesn't do so in a very coherent way --- if you make the pane very small it'll even be off the screen. And it's never anywhere near the middle.

The actual spec is pretty opaque, and the references I've found are equally unilluminating. Can anyone expand, and hopefully provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I'm a moron! The `rotateX()` in the transform for #floor should be 90deg, not 30deg. Yes, it's late.